# how to compare multiple dates in where clause in sql

Tags: sql, date, where-clause

```
 select truckid 
 from truck_log 
 where '20160804' between ruck_log.pickupdate and truck_log.ETA  
   and '20160806' between truck_log.pickupdate and truck_log.ETA
```

How to compare two dates inside where clause when I did this the query is accepting only the first comparison?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by `the query is accepting only the first comparison?`

Comment: `AND` or `OR` You should use one of them.

Comment: What's the data type of your columns? What's the behavior of the database not accepting the second comparison? I don't think the RDBMS told you "I didn't accept the second condition!". What happened? Remember that it's very important to properly handle the language to express what we want. That's important to relate with machines and even with humans. Improve your communication skills not only SQL!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add "`OR`" instead of "`AND`" in where clause :

Query :

```
select truckid from truck_log 

where  ('20160804' between truck_log.pickupdate and truck_log.ETA) 

      or ('20160806' between truck_log.pickupdate and truck_log.ETA)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `ruck_log` a typo and should be `Truck_log`?

If true, this

```
select truckid 
 from truck_log 
 where '20160804' between truck_log.pickupdate and truck_log.ETA  
   and '20160806' between truck_log.pickupdate and truck_log.ETA
```

will select all rows that have required date between pickupdate and ETA

```
          <-- 20160804   20160806 -->
pickupdate                           ETA
```

if you need to select only either one OR second, use OR clause instead of AND.